# (Multivariable) Green's Theorem Application

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, greens-theorem

Well, I'm assuming it involves Green's Theorem. I'm not too sure actually.

1. Let D be a region in the xy plane. Let A = ∬ dx dY (for region D). Let boundary of D be the region in which every point (x,y) in D is replaced by (αx, αy) for α > 0. Interpret the double integral as a Riemann Sum and find the area of αD in terms of A and α.

P.S. - How does one input a double integral on this site?

Comment: One way ia to use $$\iint$$